# Return features based on user's credentials using Geoserver WFS

Tags: security, ldap, authorization, geoserver

We are using LDAP based authentication with geoserver which is connected to a PostGIS database.
Users insert rows (features) into the table (layer) using WFS-T after authentication.

Now when users query for data from this layer (also after authentication), we would like to return data that is applicable to this user based on their credential (i.e) only view data that was inserted by that user or group.

We are storing the username in the table. We get the username because this is defined as non-null column in our table and users are required to provide it as a part of their WFS-T insert.

I read about service level security and layer level security, but what we need seems more like row level or feature level security.

We can use JDBC based authentication instead of LDAP if needed, but do not know if this will solve the problem.

I am pretty comfortable with Java and some what knowledgeable  on spring security and hence can deal with customizations if needed. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either of role-based access control (rbac) or attribute-based access control (abac). Spring Security will provide you with the former. You'll need XACML for the latter.

Once you know the identity of the user you can determine what role and group they belong to. In XACML you can define a policy which dictates how access is granted. Use XACML if there are relationships between the data you're protecting and the users accessing it.

You'll need a web service filter to intercept the request and/or the response. That filter is called a policy enforcement point in the XACML architecture.

If you have large amounts of data then you want to use something like the Axiomatics data access filter which uses XACML policies to create a SQL WHERE clause used to retrieve entitled data only.

Hth

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer. If we were to use XACML, it sounds like we will this have to customize Geoserver filters to handle request/response. Is my understanding right? Also, we may not need to restrict data on every layer (table), meaning that there some queries where everybody is allowed to see everything. Will that be possible with XACML?